# Error: finding a string within another specific string [R]

Tags: r, string, contains

I have a string of letters:

```
M <- "ABHJKFRTUIOKOPJNHGBQETYUODIOFGHJSDFKHLKJIOEQBALKFJPA"
```

And I want to see if it contains a small string:

```
S <- "FGHJ"
```

I tried the following code in R:

```
found <- ifelse(grepl(S, M), "Found","Not Found")
```

but I get the following error:

```
In grepl(S, M) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Both are S and M are class characters.

In saying that, if the string is found, is there a way to work out what position S starts and stops in M and record both positions?

I'm sure this is obvious....

Comment: Thanks @jogo - have edited.

Comment: You aren't giving us your actual value of `S`: your `S` variable has more than one item in it. Try `length(S)` and you'll see. The above three lines don't produce an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
> M = "ABHJKFRTUIOKOPJNHGBQETYUODIOFGHJSDFKHLKJIOEQBALKFJPA"
> S = "FGHJ"
> grepl(S, M)
[1] TRUE
> library(stringr)
> str_locate(M, S)
     start end
[1,]    29  32
```

Does this help? Your example isn't reproducible...

Comment: Update on my comment.  It did work when using grepl(S, M), alone, but when trying to force it to be named "found", it gives me the same error

Comment: @joeblow -- works for me. I concur with David, above -- you're not showing us the actual values of your variables.